# Can't start project on react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

```
D:\IT\Practic work\React> create-react-app test

Creating a new React app in D:\IT\Practic work\React\test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Roman Borodai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\Roman Borodai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Roman Borodai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
    at C:\Users\Roman Borodai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test/ from D:\IT\Practic work\React
Done.
```

Comment: What is your node version, npm version, and how did youu install create-react-app

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12022

Comment: Yes. Node v16.14.0.
I'm install create-react-app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it this way. Steps in sequence:

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. yarn global remove create-react-app (If yarn used)
3. npm update npx
4. npm audit fix --force
5. npx create-react-app your-app-name

I referred this post: https://betterprogramming.pub/what-to-do-if-create-react-app-doesnt-work-ad601b4c238